# How can I use html/css/jquery to change a <div> to a <tr><td>?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am doing a project and I need to put generated data in a table. However, the data that is generated is generated in a `<div>data</div>` format. I am unable to change how this data is given to me so I need to work with it. For formatting sake, I can't just keep it in the div.

How can I convert

```
<div>data</div>
```

into

```
<tr><td>data</td></tr>
```

Comment: I mean, you could just `.slice(5,-6)` the string and concatenate the tags you want around it...

Comment: Given the goal why are you not also wrapping those elements with a `<table>`? Would it be acceptable to wrap the `<div>` within the `<td>`? There are a few ways of going about this with JavaScript (or any of its libraries), but what structure do you initially receive? Why is the data generated in a structure that you don't want to use, can that be changed?